# Spotify dbus request returns empty metadata

Tags: linux, metadata, spotify, dbus

I'm running the latest version of spotify-client on Arch, and trying to talk to it with dbus.

With Spotify open, toggling pause works:

`$ dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause`

But:

`$ dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player' string:'Metadata'`

`method return sender=:1.0 -> dest=:1.8 reply_serial=2
    variant       array [
       ]`

All relevant packages are up to date, restarting does nothing, and others on IRC aren't having this problem.

Is there something, obvious or otherwise, that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found what's causing the problem, a solution not so much.
Did you perhaps set `ui.track_notifications_enabled=false`in your Spotify prefs?
That might be causing Spotify to not send data to the dbus interface.

Let's hope someone has an answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653366/linux-spotify-metadata-through-dbus-with-track-notifications-disabled

https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/Linux-Spotify-metadata-through-DBUS-with-track-notifications/m-p/1003753#M105963

https://askubuntu.com/questions/565464/spotify-metadata-through-dbus-with-track-notifications-disabled

Comment: The problem has since gone away and I don't recall if that was the source; however, accepting your answer since it seems logical. I may have reinstalled Spotify and thereby reset the defaults or something.